# Tracking the location using GPS in iPhone crashes app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, dictionary, core-location

This may be simple for those who interested in GPS based applications.In my app,i am trying to  track the location of a user and have to draw the user's path on map.So on each updated point i have to populate an array which is having the values like latitude,longitude,altitude,current speed,distance travelled of that particular location.But when i am trying it on device,my app crashes while taking these values.I think this method is calling more than 10 times per second.

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation*)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
}
```

And taking all these bulk values at a very fast rate causes the issue.I tried to implement a condition in this method so that the array should update at a time interval of 5 seconds.this is what i tried.

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation*)newLocation  fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation{

      CLLocation*  updatedLocation = [newLocation retain];
        NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        NSDate *myDate = (NSDate *)[prefs objectForKey:@"myDateKey"];

        NSDate *lastDate = (NSDate *)newLocation.timestamp;
        NSTimeInterval theDiff = [lastDate timeIntervalSinceDate:myDate];

       if (theDiff > 5.0f || myDate == nil){
            //do your webservices stuff here



          if (newLocation.horizontalAccuracy < 0)
        {
            // No Signal
            if([self conformsToProtocol:@protocol(CoreLocationControllerDelegate)])
            {

                [self gpsSignalStatus:@"No Signal"];
            }

        }
        else if (newLocation.horizontalAccuracy > 65)
        {
            // Poor Signal
            if([self conformsToProtocol:@protocol(CoreLocationControllerDelegate)])
            {

                [self gpsSignalStatus:@"Poor Signal"];
            }
        }
        else if (newLocation.horizontalAccuracy <= 65.0)
        {
            // Fair
            if([self conformsToProtocol:@protocol(CoreLocationControllerDelegate)])
            {

                [self gpsSignalStatus:@"Fair"];
            }

        }
        else if (newLocation.horizontalAccuracy <= 20.0)
        {
            // Good
            if([self conformsToProtocol:@protocol(CoreLocationControllerDelegate)])
            {

                [self gpsSignalStatus:@" Good"];
            }

        }

        int degrees = newLocation.coordinate.latitude;
        double decimal = fabs(newLocation.coordinate.latitude - degrees);
        int minutes = decimal * 60;
        double seconds = decimal * 3600 - minutes * 60;
        NSString *lat = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d° %d' %1.4f\"",
                         degrees, minutes, seconds];
        latitudeLabel.text = lat;
        degrees = newLocation.coordinate.longitude;
        decimal = fabs(newLocation.coordinate.longitude - degrees);
        minutes = decimal * 60;
        seconds = decimal * 3600 - minutes * 60;
        NSString *longt = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d° %d' %1.4f\"",
                           degrees, minutes, seconds];
        longitudeLabel.text = longt;
        speedLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SPEED: %f", [newLocation speed]];
        altitudeLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"ALTITUDE: %f", [newLocation altitude]];
        [mapView removeAnnotations:[mapView annotations]];
        MKPointAnnotation *pa = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];
        pa.coordinate = newLocation.coordinate;
        pa.title = @"Current Location";
        [mapView addAnnotation:pa];
        [pa release];
        NSString *latlongString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f,%f", newLocation.coordinate.latitude,newLocation.coordinate.longitude];
        [latLongArray addObject:latlongString];
        NSLog(@"%@",latLongArray);
        NSLog(@"Speed :: %g meters/sec",newLocation.speed);


        [points addObject:newLocation];
        NSInteger tot = [points count];
        MKMapPoint* pointsToUse=malloc(sizeof(CLLocationCoordinate2D) * tot);
        if(tot>1)
        {
            //i=tot-1;i<tot;i++
            for(int i=0;i<tot;i++)
            {

                CLLocation *Loc=[points objectAtIndex:i];
                CLLocationDegrees latitude = Loc.coordinate.latitude;
                //   [TravellingCoordinates addObject:location];
                CLLocationDegrees longitude = Loc.coordinate.longitude;
                CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude, longitude);
                MKMapPoint point = MKMapPointForCoordinate(coordinate);
                pointsToUse[i] = point;




                NSString *latitudestr = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%g", newLocation.coordinate.latitude];
                NSLog(@"Latitude: %@", latitudestr);


                NSString *longitudestr = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%g", newLocation.coordinate.longitude];
                NSLog(@"Longitude: %@", longitudestr);

                NSString *altitudestr = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%g",newLocation.altitude];
                NSLog(@"altitude: %@", altitudestr);

                NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
                [formatter setDateFormat: @"HH:mm:ss"];
                NSString *LocationTime=[formatter stringFromDate:newLocation.timestamp];
                NSLog(@"LocationTime:%@",LocationTime);
                NSTimeInterval timeSinceLastLocation = [oldLocation.timestamp timeIntervalSinceDate:newLocation.timestamp];
                CGFloat speed = newLocation.speed;
                NSString *speedstr=[[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%f",speed];
                NSLog(@"%@",speedstr);

                CLLocationDistance distance=0;;
                distance=distance+[newLocation distanceFromLocation:oldLocation];
                NSString *distancestr=[[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%f",distance];

               // NSString *distancestr=[[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%f",distance];

                [firstJsonDictionary setObject:latitudestr forKey:@"latitude"];
                [firstJsonDictionary setObject:longitudestr forKey:@"longitude"];
                [firstJsonDictionary setObject:altitudestr forKey:@"altitude"];
                [firstJsonDictionary setObject:LocationTime forKey:@"timestamp"];
                [firstJsonDictionary setObject:speedstr forKey:@"speed"];
                [firstJsonDictionary setObject:distancestr forKey:@"distance"];

                for(int i=0;i<10;i++){

                    [arr addObject:firstJsonDictionary];
                    // [firstJsonDictionary release];
                }
                NSError *error=nil;
                NSData *jsonData2 = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:arr options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&error];
                NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData2 encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
              //  NSLog(@"jsonData as string:\n%@", jsonString);
                NSUserDefaults *defaults=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
                [defaults setObject:jsonString forKey:@"jsonarraydata"];



                } 

            }

        // create the polyline based on the array of points.
        _routeLine = [MKPolyline polylineWithPoints:pointsToUse count:tot];
        [mapView addOverlay:_routeLine];
        free(pointsToUse);
           NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
           [prefs setObject:lastDate forKey:@"myDateKey"];
           [prefs synchronize];

           [self distanceTravelled:newLocation];
       [self loadRoute];


       }



    }
```

Any idea will be appreciable. Thanks in advance.

Comment: show us the log report on crash..

Comment: actually i couldn't logged it out on live testing.After moving a distance,the entire ui becomes hanged and it crashes later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you allocating your locationManager you should set a distance filter:

```
CLLocationManager *locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation;
locationManager.distanceFilter = 100.0;
```

If you don't set the distance filter it takes the default value kCLDistanceFilterNone and you will be notified about ALL movements(i.e the method didUpdateLocation will be called very often)

Comment: i have given it like this  locMgr.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone; at the time of allocation.

Comment: wat does this mean?locationManager.distanceFilter = 100.0;

Comment: it is "The minimum distance (measured in meters) a device must move horizontally before an update event is generated."

Comment: but the same thing happens..after moved about 500 mts,the entire app hangs.I have set a timer  in the view.After moving this much distance,the timer also not updating the time

Comment: You should provide a crash log - test your app on simulator (you can simulate movement in iOS Simulator - Debug - Location - City Run)

Comment: Ya i already tried that with adding gpx files.On simulator it show the drawing and timer is also working fine.But the issue is happening on live testing.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17097/discussion-between-alpz-and-stas)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the accepted answer, you need to add the following code to fetch lat / long in iOS 8.

```
if ([locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestWhenInUseAuthorization)])
    {
        [locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
    }
```

and you need to add `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` key in your plist file.

Read [this link](http://nevan.net/2014/09/core-location-manager-changes-in-ios-8/) for more details.